# React - reduce amount of objects returned from Object.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to limit the amount of objects returned when using Object.keys.map? I want to map over some data and render some jsx, but I only want 5 items returned, but there's 20+ in the dataset.

I've seen people use .slice with arrays to do this, but I don't think I can do that with an object?

```
return Object.keys(items).map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <li>
          <a href={`/${items[item].link}`}>{items[item].title}</a>
        </li>
      )
    })
```

Comment: you can do that after keys. Object.keys(items).slice(0,5).map(...). It is possible to slice after, but like this map will do only on 5, otherwise it would on all than drop all rest

Comment: try to use filter() and remove out things that you dont want and just iterate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

map will return an array. So you can slice it after map has returned the array.

```
return Object.keys(items).map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <li>
          <a href={`/${items[item].link}`}>{items[item].title}</a>
        </li>
      )
    }).slice(0,5)
```

(or)

```
return Object.keys(items).slice(0,5).map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <a href={`/${items[item].link}`}>{items[item].title}</a>
            </li>
          )
        })
```

Second perform better

Comment: Just to add, regarding performance, would be better to first slice than map.

Comment: You should probably do the slice before the map

Answer (score 0):

```
return Object.keys(items).map((item, key) => {
    if (key < 4) {
        return (
            <li>
            <a href={`/${items[item].link}`}>{items[item].title}</a>
            </li>
        )}
    })
```

You will be mapping the object and since you have the key you can check if you reached the limit that you can set.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Yeah sure. From now on I will try to add them.